# Django UpdateView generating 'GET' request instead of 'POST'

Tags: python, html, django

I'm following along a book called Django for Beginners and creating a project which displays newspaper articles. Part of the functionality is being able to edit those articles. I've followed along as closely as I could but I'm still getting an error when hitting the 'Update' button:

[image]

[image]

My urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (ArticleListView,
 ArticleUpdateView, 
 ArticleDetailView,
 ArticleDeleteView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/edit/', ArticleUpdateView.as_view(), name = 'article_edit'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name = 'article_detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', ArticleDeleteView.as_view(), name = 'article_delete'),
    path('', ArticleListView.as_view(), name = 'article_list'),
]
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Article

# Create your views here.
class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_list.html'

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_detail.html'

class ArticleUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Article
    fields = ('title', 'body')
    template_name = 'article_edit.html'

class ArticleDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')
```

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

My HTML:

```
<!-- templates/article_edit.html -->    
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    
{% block content %}
<h1>Edit</h1>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}\
<button class="btn btn-info ml-2" type="submit">Update Article {{article.pk}}</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

After hitting the edit button, according to the book the app is supposed to forward me to the 'article_detail' page however that is not happening.

Any assistance would be gratefully received.

Thanks
Andy

Comment: set the action `url` in your form : `<form action="{% url 'article_edit' article.pk %}" method="post">`

Comment: That didn't work. :( Pressing the Update button results in the app trying to take me to 'articles/1/edit/None' which doesn't exist in any of my URL patterns. Including the action url in the form results in a "GET /articles/2/edit/None HTTP/1.1" 404 3146 in the terminal.

Comment: What if you try another update url pattern : `'/edit/<int:pk>/'`

Comment: Now it's coming back with ""GET /articles/edit/2/None HTTP/1.1" 404 3146" in the terminal. I don't know why, when I've declared the url pattern, it's tacking 'None' on at the end. And why, when the html form 'method' attribute = 'post', it attempts a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was a simple omission of a return statement in the get_absolute_url function within models.py.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).